# SQL Server : convert multiple XML to table

Tags: sql-server, xml

I am currently able to get 1 XML converted into a table but am trying to get ALL xml into a single table. I have about 6 million XML entries that I'd like to do all at once then sort. Any ideas?

```
DECLARE @docHandle INT;
SET @docHandle = 0;

DECLARE @xml XML;

SELECT @xml = XMLData
FROM DaTable
WHERE FileType = 'Transaction';

EXEC sp_xml_preparedocument @docHandle OUTPUT, @xml;

SELECT sub.id, sub.localname, val.[text]
FROM OPENXML(@docHandle, N'') AS par
LEFT JOIN OPENXML(@docHandle, N'') AS sub
    ON sub.parentid = par.id
LEFT JOIN OPENXML(@docHandle, N'') AS val
    ON val.parentid = sub.id

WHERE sub.localname != 'xsd'
  AND sub.localname != 'xsi'
  AND sub.localname != '#text';
```

Output:

```
id  localname           text
---------------------------------------------
4   ID                  436875364
5   TP_CUSTOMER_ID      400108792109
6   TP_ACCOUNT_ID       400204158957
7   TP_ACCOUNT_TXN_ID   409420594138
8   INSTITUTION_TXN_ID  INTUIT-409420594138
9   POSTED_DATE         2016-05-14T03:00:00
```

Comment: Show us some of the XML too.  This should be easily do-able with the XML methods instead of OPENXML.  But the it's different enough that we need to see what the XML looks like.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Think you would just use a cursor for this.

```
DECLARE @xml XML;
DECLARE @cursor CURSOR;
SET @cursor = CURSOR FAST_FORWARD FOR
SELECT XMLData FROM DaTable WHERE FileType = 'Transaction';

DECLARE @result TABLE
    (tag_name nvarchar(100) NOT NULL,
    xml_text nvarchar(100) NOT NULL);

OPEN @cursor;
WHILE 1 = 1 BEGIN
    FETCH NEXT FROM @cursor INTO @xml;
    IF @@FETCH_STATUS < 0 BREAK;

    INSERT INTO @result (tag_name, xml_text)
    SELECT node.value('local-name(..)', 'nvarchar(100)'),
        node.value('.', 'nvarchar(100)')
    FROM @xml.nodes('//text()') q(node);
END;

CLOSE @cursor;
DEALLOCATE @cursor;

SELECT tag_name, xml_text FROM @result;
```

Answer (score 0):

If the schema of the xml files is all the same then I would recommend that you simply combine the xml files into a single file via PowerShell. Then and then run your query in SQL Server on the combined file.

The following power shell script that I found right here on stack overflow should do the job:

```
    $xmldoc = new-object xml
    $rootnode = $xmldoc.createelement("xml")
    $xmldoc.appendchild($rootnode)
    $dec = $xmldoc.CreateXmlDeclaration("1.0", $null, $null)
    $xmldoc.InsertBefore($dec, $rootnode)
    $files = gci "c:\source_files\*.xml" 
    foreach ($file in $files) {
        $xmltoadd = select-xml -path $file.FullName -xpath "/*"
        $xml2 = $xmltoadd.node.InnerXml
        $finalxml += $xml2
    }
    $rootnode.innerxml = $finalxml
    $xmldoc.Save("C:\final_output\combined.xml")
```

Replace the directory string “c:\source_files\” with your directory where the xml files are located. Also change the save location “C:\final_output\combined.xml” to your desired output file location.